# Write a program that find the largest integer in a string

Tags: python, string

Write a program that find the largest integer in a string. `'abcd51kkk3kk19ghi'` would output `51`.

I am having a hard time putting two digit integers into the list.

```py
s = input('Enter a sequence of strings: ')
lst = []

for i in range(0, len(s)):
 if s[i].isdigit() == True:
  lst.append(s[i])

print(lst)
```

Comment: Is this your actual code?

Comment: I want to read the string, find the digits, put them into a string using append(), cas them to integers and then use max() to find the largest.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow! Beginners are welcome, but we expect a certain amount of effort to be expended on attempting to solve your own problem prior to a question being posted. We don't write code for you although we are very willing to help you fix issues with code you have written.

Answer (score 5):

This problem is a good fit for regular expressions:

```
In [8]: max(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', s)))
Out[8]: 51
```

Here, `r'\d+'` matches a sequence of one or more decimal digits.  The matching strings are then converted to integers, and the maximum is taken.

A slightly more verbose way to write the same thing is

```
In [9]: max(int(digits) for digits in re.findall(r'\d+', s))
Out[9]: 51
```

Comment: Is their a more basic way to do this as my prof has not taught re.findall yet

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` and a comprehension:

```
max(int(''.join(v)) for k, v in groupby(s, str.isdigit) if k)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution, if you don't want to use regex:

```py
s = input("Enter a sequence of strings: ")
current_num = ""  # A string containing the current number that is being read
current_max = 0   # The maximum number found so far


for ch in s:  # Iterate on the string, character by character
    if ch.isdigit():
        current_num += ch  # append the digit ch to the current number
    elif current_num:  # if we just finished reading a number
        current_max = max(int(current_num), current_max)
        current_num = ""

if current_num:  # in case there is no character after the last number
    current_max = max(int(current_num), current_max)

print(current_max)
```

Comment: What does this line do? current_max = max(int(current_num), current_max)

Comment: If int(current_num) is bigger than the current_max, then current_max will be replaced. Otherwise, it stays the same. It is equivalent to
if int(current_num) > current_max:
    current_max = int(current_num)

Comment: Do you need the current_num = "" again in the elif statement?

Comment: Yes, this resets the current_num when it's finished, otherwise, it could be for example '51319'